# How to save variables from a console text in Python?

Tags: python, variables

What code should I use to write a program that stores the following content in a variable? 
**I cannot use an external file.**

```
{'title':'El Más Allá','aka':'E tu vivrai nel terrore - Laldilà','director':'Lucio Fulci', 'year':1981, 'country':'Italia'}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What have you already tried, and where are you stuck? If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

just store it in a dict like this

```py
import json
instr = input(">>>")

myDict = json.loads(instr)
```

Comment: I think the input is a string, not just code.